# Changing character variable to numeric variable

Tags: sas

Hello i have a table which has numerous columns i.e name,age,country, gender etc, i'm a student who is trying to use SAS for a module. There has purposely been some wrong data placed in columns - For example Gender is either Male or Female but i'm essentially looking to turn male or female into either 1 or 2 i.e 1=Male/2=Female but when i use the code that i think is correct to do this i get the error expecting a format name (error 22-322) as well as (76-322) syntax error, statement will be ignored

More than happy to send any data or examples of additional code if that helps.

If someone could help me this would be massively appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as well as provide more detailed error messages along with code? What have you tried, what's the problem, and what can people help you with?

Comment: At minimum please show the code you're using and some small sample data as well. If you need to generate sample data see this post for instructions: https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Communities-Library/How-to-create-a-data-step-version-of-your-data-AKA-generate/ta-p/258712